# Hash function returns same hash when keys have same length

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I am looking for a hash function in java that for keys with same length returns the same hash.

```
            int index1 = hashmap.hash("xxx");
            int index2 = hashmap.hash("yyy");
            assertEquals(index1, index2);
```

I am using this function:

```
public int hash(String x) {
    int hashCode = x.hashCode();
    return (int) ( ( Math.abs( hash_a * hashCode + hash_b) % p_prime ) % capacity ); 
}
```

Comment: what are `hash_a`, `hash_b`, `capacity`, and `p_prime`?

Comment: Can't you just take the length of the string as the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution just pass the length of the input string to an arbitrary hash function.

As you will pass the length of string, it could be done by a little change to your function like the following:

```
// hash_a, hash_b, p_prime, and capacity variables are defined in a class.
public int hash(String x) {
    int hashCode = x.length(); // this line is updated
    return (int) ( ( Math.abs( hash_a * hashCode + hash_b) % p_prime ) % capacity ); 
}
```

Comment: But how works with the capacity and which parameters should I use to get the hash?